# How to proceed with spoj LGIC?

Tags: math, sequence, factorial

I am trying to solve this problem http://www.spoj.pl/problems/LGIC/. I just can't figure out how is this sequence advancing.

By lagarange's it is too complex to solve for such a great range.

The farthest I could get was with factorials

```
  1! = 1   & a1=2
  2! = 2   & a2=4
  3! = 6   & a3=11
  4! = 24  & a4=36
  5! = 120 & a5=147
  6! = 720 & a6=778
```

Please guide me someone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the sequence is: An = n! + 2^n - n.

Answer (score 0):

You can gat the Nth term using

T(n) = n! + pow(2,n) - n